# RadiobuttonFor is not working for property inside a colletion (ASP.Net MVC3)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, view, html-helper

My view model looks like :

```
public class ShippingInfo
{
    public string DiagID { get; set; }

    public Collection<AddressInfo> AddressSuggestions { get; set; }
}


public class AddressInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompleteAddressInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to Post the form upon Button click, the radio button selection is not persisted in my action method.

Do I need to use another variable to store the selection, as we do in case of Dropdown list?

```
@if (Model.AddressSuggestions != null)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddressSuggestions.Count; i++)
    {
        AddressInfo m1 = Model.AddressSuggestions[i];
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m1.CompleteAddressInfo, m1.ID)
        <span>@Model.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo</span>
        <br/>
    }
    }
```

I am expecting my radio button selection should persist in the Model when I am posting the form (Model Binding). I would appreciate if anyone points out the problem in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@` in front of your `Html.RadioButtonFor` helper call, otherwise you are not outputting anything to the view. Also get rid of the `;` at the end of this helper call:

```
@if (Model.AddressSuggestions != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddressSuggestions.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(
            m => m.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo, 
            Model.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo
        )
    }
}
```

Also I don't know what you are meaning with the `false` argument but there's no overload of this helper that expects a boolean. The second argument of the helper represents the value that will make the radio button checked if the corresponding model property value matches.

So for example if you wanted to have 2 mutually exclusive radio buttons per row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddressSuggestions.Count; i++)
{
    <span>Value 1</span>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(
        m => m.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo, 
        "value1"
    )

    <span>Value 2</span>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(
        m => m.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo, 
        "value2"
    )
}
```

Now if `Model.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo` equals `value1` then the first radio button will be preselected and if it equals `value2` the second will be preselected.

Once again it will depend on what you are trying to achieve and what values does your model holds.

Comment: Basically I want to keep all the radio buttons unchecked. I thought         public static MvcHtmlString RadioButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, bool isChecked); definition will work & thus I m entering false as the last parameter.

Comment: The if block is having @ sign, so I thought whatever code inside the block needs no @ sign again. Thus not used @ for Html.RadioButtonFor. Please Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Biki, the difference between `if` and `Html.RadioButtonFor` is that the first is just a condition which doesn't return anything whereas the second is a Html helper which outputs HTML fragments. And in Razor if you want to output something you could use the `@` function.

Comment: If I m using @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo, Model.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo) then both the radio buttons are coming as selected by default. Where as I want them to be unchecked by default. Do I need to achieve this again by Jquery?

Comment: No, you don't need to achieve that by using jQuery. You achieve that by using the second argument. As I explained in my answer if the model property equals this second argument value then the radio will be checked. And since you are using `Model.AddressSuggestions[i].CompleteAddressInfo` as second argument it is obvious that the radio button will be checked. You have used the same value as the first argument. So adjust this second argument to a correct value that you need.

Comment: Hi Darin, As per your comment I ve modified my code above, but the user selection is still not getting persisted in the Form Post.